# Почему при делении целого автоматически получается float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например:

```py
a = int(input()) 
рrint(a/3)
```

И без разницы, делится нацело или с остатком.

Comment: Удивительно, что на этот вопрос дубликата нет. Азы.

Comment: потому что `/` в питоне = нецелочисленное деление, а для целочисленного есть особый оператор `//`

Answer (score 7):

Оператор `/` в третьем Питоне всегда возвращает вещественное число. Такое правило. Используйте `//` для деления нацело.

### [6.7. Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=operators#binary-arithmetic-operations)

> The / (division) and // (floor division) operators yield the quotient
> of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a
> common type. Division of integers yields a float, while floor division
> of integers results in an integer; the result is that of mathematical
> division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result. Division by
> zero raises the ZeroDivisionError exception.